# high volume / high resolution capable timeline data visualizer

Tags: javascript, python, data-visualization, unix

I am routinely in a need of working with high frequency event timelines, mainly to cross-correlate load-related issues in a complex environments. Potentially hundreds of thousands of individual entries, microsecond resolution. At the moment I am mostly using Python Matplotlib (manually rendering individual bars) and amcharts/gantt. Both are usable, but none is fast enough to be pleasant to work with on a 3ghz machine.

Is there anything else around from free/OSS/unix/web world which I could try? Maybe written in C++/Qt?

Addition (more background):

The question is not about real time processing but about dealing with lots of high resolution timelines (usually hours of microsecond precision from each thread activity and from threshold-based metrics in a dozen of processes). For after-the-fact issue root cause analysis.

Loading time alone would not be a big problem, but the latency of zooming, scrolling, selecting, etc. is a real annoyance, and the investigation of a distributed event usally requires quite a bit of those.

Comment: Do you ***really*** need to see it in real-time?

Comment: Not real time, but lots of high resolution timelines (usually hours of microsecond precision from each thread activity and from threshold-based metrics in a dozen of processes). For after-the-fact issue root cause analysis.

Comment: Then processing time doesn't really matter. Just kick it off & go for coffee/lunch/home?

Comment: Loading time alone would not be a biggie, but the latency of zooming, scrolling, etc. are a pain, plus sometimes the answer is needed rather quickly :-)

Comment: Ah, now I see. Sorry to be so obtuse. You should probably edit your question to mention details such as the latency of zooming, scrolling, etc

Comment: @Mawg - good point, thanks. I have updated the question as you suggested.